# How to control button click according to the values stored in a variable using android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

I have made an android app using android studio were through bluetooth module (hc05) and arduino I'm sending sensor data to the app. I have added a torch application in it and willing to control it's on and off according to the range set for the value that gets stored in amount variable.

I had convert the string value of DATA into integer and stored it in amount variable. For this conversion I used:
amount = Integer.parseInt(DATA);

The torch on and off button is through Image button.

Java code:

```js
package com.example.sugandhabansal.bluetooth_torch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class bluetooth_torch_Activity extends Activity
{
    TextView myLabel,mydata,myvalue;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;
    private CameraManager mCameraManager;
    private String mCameraId;
    private ImageButton mTorchOnOffButton;
    private Boolean isTorchOn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("bluetooth_torch", "onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_torch_);

        Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
        Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
        myvalue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);
        mydata = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);

        //Open Button
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    findBT();
                    openBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });

        //Close button
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    closeBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });

        mTorchOnOffButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_on_off);
        isTorchOn = false;

        Boolean isFlashAvailable = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!isFlashAvailable) {

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(bluetooth_torch_Activity.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setTitle("Error !!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device doesn't support flash light!");
            alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // closing the application
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return;
        }


        mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mTorchOnOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (isTorchOn) {
                            turnOffFlashLight();
                            isTorchOn = false;
                    } else {
                            turnOnFlashLight();
                            isTorchOn = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void findBT()
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            {
                if(device.getName().equals("HC-05"))
                {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
    }

    void openBT() throws IOException
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Connected");
    }

    void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 35; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String DATA = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    Log.d("SKY",DATA);
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;


                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            mydata.setText(DATA);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }


    void closeBT() throws IOException
    {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
    }

    public void turnOnFlashLight() {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
                    mTorchOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    public void turnOffFlashLight() {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, false);
                    mTorchOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(isTorchOn){
            turnOffFlashLight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(isTorchOn){
            turnOffFlashLight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(isTorchOn){
            turnOnFlashLight();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sugandhabansal.bluetooth_torch">

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="bluetooth_torch_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout design xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bluetooth Connection"
        android:layout_below="@+id/open"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Open"
        android:layout_above="@+id/value"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Value:  "
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/close" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="data"
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/value"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/value" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/button_on_off"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:src="@drawable/off"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: question is not clear , even not 1%. what u wanna do with amount value? what u mean by control torch. When ask a question make sure u tell people what u wanna know.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the docs about how to ask a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: according to the value in amount, I want to control the imagebutton of torch. That is, when amount=10 then torch should get on and when amount=20 then torch should get off

Comment: Can I use performClick() or callOnClick() function to trigger the image button pragmatically to on an off the torch?  And if I can, then please provide me with the code with which I can do it as I'm new to android studio.

Comment: Someone please reply to me....I'm really stuck......If the question is still not clear then please tell me.....I'll edit the question again.....